# Протокол camd35

Tags: c++

Кто знаком с данным протоколом?
Необходимо реализовать его на пик контроллере. 
Вот, что удалось найти:
интересует процесс шифрования данных и оформление в UDP

```
#define MODULE_LOG_PREFIX "camd35"

#include "globals.h"
#if defined MODULE_CAMD35 || defined MODULE_CAMD35_TCP

#include "cscrypt/md5.h"
#include "module-cacheex.h"
#include "module-camd35.h"
#include "module-camd35-cacheex.h"
#include "oscam-aes.h"
#include "oscam-chk.h"
#include "oscam-cache.h"
#include "oscam-client.h"
#include "oscam-ecm.h"
#include "oscam-emm.h"
#include "oscam-net.h"
#include "oscam-string.h"
#include "oscam-reader.h"

//CMD00 - ECM (request)
//CMD01 - ECM (response)
//CMD02 - EMM (in clientmode - set EMM, in server mode - EMM data) - obsolete
//CMD03 - ECM (cascading request)
//CMD04 - ECM (cascading response)
//CMD05 - EMM (emm request) send cardata/cardinfo to client
//CMD06 - EMM (incomming EMM in server mode)
//CMD19 - EMM (incomming EMM in server mode) only seen with caid 0x1830
//CMD08 - Stop sending requests to the server for current srvid,prvid,caid
//CMD44 - MPCS/OScam internal error notification
//CMD55 - connect_on_init/keepalive

//CMD0x3c - CACHEEX Cache-push filter request
//CMD0x3d - CACHEEX Cache-push id request
//CMD0x3e - CACHEEX Cache-push id answer
//CMD0x3f - CACHEEX cache-push

//used variable ncd_skey for storing remote node id: ncd_skey[0..7] : 8
//bytes node id ncd_skey[8] : 1=valid node id received

#define REQ_SIZE    MAX_ECM_SIZE + 20 + 0x34

static int32_t __camd35_send(struct s_client *cl, uchar *buf, int32_t buflen, int answer_awaited)
{
    int32_t l;
    unsigned char rbuf[REQ_SIZE + 15 + 4], *sbuf = rbuf + 4;

    if(!cl->udp_fd || !cl->crypted) { return (-1); }  //exit if no fd or aes key not set!

    //Fix ECM len > 255
    if(buflen <= 0)
        { buflen = ((buf[0] == 0) ? (((buf[21] & 0x0f) << 8) | buf[22]) + 3 : buf[1]); }
    l = 20 + (((buf[0] == 3) || (buf[0] == 4)) ? 0x34 : 0) + buflen;
    memcpy(rbuf, cl->ucrc, 4);
    memcpy(sbuf, buf, l);
    memset(sbuf + l, 0xff, 15); // set unused space to 0xff for newer camd3's
    i2b_buf(4, crc32(0L, sbuf + 20, buflen), sbuf + 4);
    l = boundary(4, l);
    cs_log_dump_dbg(cl->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, sbuf, l, "send %d bytes to %s", l, username(cl));
    aes_encrypt_idx(cl->aes_keys, sbuf, l);

    int32_t status;
    if(cl->is_udp)
    {
        status = sendto(cl->udp_fd, rbuf, l + 4, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cl->udp_sa, cl->udp_sa_len);
        if(status == -1) { set_null_ip(&SIN_GET_ADDR(cl->udp_sa)); }
    }
    else
    {
        status = send(cl->udp_fd, rbuf, l + 4, 0);

        if(cl->typ == 'p' && cl->reader)
        {
            if(status == -1) { network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "can't send"); }
        }
        else if(cl->typ == 'c')
        {
            if(status == -1) { cs_disconnect_client(cl); }
        }
    }
    if(status != -1)
    {
        if(cl->reader && answer_awaited)
        {
            cl->reader->last_s = time(NULL);
        }
        if(cl->reader && !answer_awaited)
        {
            cl->reader->last_s = cl->reader->last_g = time(NULL);
        }
        cl->last = time(NULL);

    }
    return status;
}

int32_t camd35_send(struct s_client *cl, uchar *buf, int32_t buflen)
{
    // send command and set sending time because we await response
    return __camd35_send(cl, buf, buflen, 1);
}

int32_t camd35_send_without_timeout(struct s_client *cl, uchar *buf, int32_t buflen)
{
    // send command and do NOT set sending time because we DON'T await response
    return __camd35_send(cl, buf, buflen, 0);
}

static int32_t camd35_auth_client(struct s_client *cl, uchar *ucrc)
{
    int32_t rc = 1, no_delay = 1;
    uint32_t crc;
    struct s_auth *account;
    unsigned char md5tmp[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    if(cl->upwd[0])
        { return (memcmp(cl->ucrc, ucrc, 4) ? 1 : 0); }
    cl->crypted = 1;
    crc = (((ucrc[0] << 24) | (ucrc[1] << 16) | (ucrc[2] << 8) | ucrc[3]) & 0xffffffffL);
    for(account = cfg.account; (account) && (!cl->upwd[0]); account = account->next)
        if(crc == crc32(0L, MD5((unsigned char *)account->usr, strlen(account->usr), md5tmp), MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        {
            rc = cs_auth_client(cl, account, NULL);
            if(!rc)
            {
                memcpy(cl->ucrc, ucrc, 4);
                cs_strncpy((char *)cl->upwd, account->pwd, sizeof(cl->upwd));
                if (!aes_set_key_alloc(&cl->aes_keys, (char *) MD5(cl->upwd, strlen((char *)cl->upwd), md5tmp)))
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                #ifdef CS_CACHEEX
                if(cl->account->cacheex.mode < 2)
                #endif
                if(!cl->is_udp && cl->tcp_nodelay == 0)
                {
                    setsockopt(cl->udp_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&no_delay, sizeof(no_delay));
                    cl->tcp_nodelay = 1;
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }
    return (rc);
}

static int32_t camd35_recv(struct s_client *client, uchar *buf, int32_t l)
{
    int32_t rc, s, rs, n = 0, buflen = 0, len = 0;
    for(rc = rs = s = 0; !rc; s++)
    {
        switch(s)
        {
        case 0:
            if(!client->udp_fd) { return (-9); }
            if(client->is_udp && client->typ == 'c')
            {
                rs = recv_from_udpipe(buf);
            }
            else
            {
                //read minimum packet size (4 byte ucrc + 32 byte data) to detect packet size (tcp only)

                //rs = cs_recv(client->udp_fd, buf, client->is_udp ? l : 36, 0);
                if(client->is_udp){
                    while (1){
                    rs = cs_recv(client->udp_fd, buf, l, 0);
                        if (rs < 0){
                            if(errno == EINTR) { continue; }  // try again in case of interrupt
                            if(errno == EAGAIN) { continue; }  //EAGAIN needs select procedure again
                            cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, "ERROR: %s (errno=%d %s)", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
                            break;
                        }else {break;}
                    }
                }else{
                    int32_t tot=36, readed=0;
                    rs = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        readed = cs_recv(client->udp_fd, buf+rs, tot, 0);
                        if (readed < 0){
                            if(errno == EINTR) { continue; }  // try again in case of interrupt
                            if(errno == EAGAIN) { continue; }  //EAGAIN needs select procedure again
                            cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, "ERROR: %s (errno=%d %s)", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
                            break;
                        }
                        if (readed == 0){ // nothing to read left!
                            rc = -5;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (readed > 0){ // received something, add it!
                            tot-=readed;
                        rs+=readed;
                        }
                    }
                    while(tot!=0);
                }

            }
            if(rs < 36)
            {   
                if(rc != -5)
                    { rc = -1; }
                goto out;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            switch(camd35_auth_client(client, buf))
            {
            case  0:
                break;  // ok
            case  1:
                rc = -2;
                break; // unknown user
            default:
                rc = -9;
                break; // error's from cs_auth()
            }
            memmove(buf, buf + 4, rs -= 4);
            break;
        case 2:
            aes_decrypt(client->aes_keys, buf, rs);
            if(rs != boundary(4, rs))
                cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER,
                              "WARNING: packet size has wrong decryption boundary");

            n = (buf[0] == 3) ? 0x34 : 0;

            //Fix for ECM request size > 255 (use ecm length field)
            if(buf[0] == 0)
                { buflen = (((buf[21] & 0x0f) << 8) | buf[22]) + 3; }
            else if(buf[0] == 0x3d || buf[0] == 0x3e || buf[0] == 0x3f)  //cacheex-push
                { buflen = buf[1] | (buf[2] << 8); }
            else
                { buflen = buf[1]; }

            n = boundary(4, n + 20 + buflen);
            if(!(client->is_udp && client->typ == 'c') && (rs < n) && ((n - 32) > 0))
            {

                //len = cs_recv(client->udp_fd, buf+32, n-32, 0); // read the rest of the packet
                int32_t tot=n-32, readed=0;
                len = 0;
                do{
                    readed = cs_recv(client->udp_fd, buf+32+len, tot, 0); // read the rest of the packet
                    if (readed < 0){
                        if(errno == EINTR) { continue; }  // try again in case of interrupt
                        if(errno == EAGAIN) { continue; }  //EAGAIN needs select procedure again
                        cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, "ERROR: %s (errno=%d %s)", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
                        break;
                    }
                    if (readed == 0){ // nothing to read left!
                        break;
                    }
                    if (readed > 0){ // received something, add it!
                    tot-=readed;
                    len+=readed;
                    }
                }
                while(tot!=0);


                if(len > 0)
                {
                    rs += len;
                    aes_decrypt(client->aes_keys, buf + 32, len);
                }
                if(len < 0)
                {
                    rc = -1;
                    goto out;
                }
            }

            cs_log_dump_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER,
                          buf, rs, "received %d bytes from %s", rs, remote_txt());

            if(n < rs)
                cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER,
                              "ignoring %d bytes of garbage", rs - n);
            else if(n > rs) { rc = -3; }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(crc32(0L, buf + 20, buflen) != b2i(4, buf + 4)) { rc = -4; }
            if(!rc) { rc = n; }
            break;
        }
    }

out:
    if((rs > 0) && ((rc == -1) || (rc == -2)))
    {
        cs_log_dump_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, buf, rs,
                      "received %d bytes from %s (native)", rs, remote_txt());
    }
    if(rc >= 0) { client->last = time(NULL); }  // last client action is now
    switch(rc)
    {
        //case 0:   break;
    case -1:
        cs_log("packet is too small (received %d bytes, expected %d bytes)", rs, l);
        break;
    case -2:
        if(cs_auth_client(client, 0, "unknown user"))
            { cs_disconnect_client(client); }
        break;
    case -3:
        cs_log("incomplete request !");
        break;
    case -4:
        cs_log("checksum error (wrong password ?)");
        break;
    case -5:
        cs_log_dbg(client->typ == 'c' ? D_CLIENT : D_READER, "connection closed");
        break;      
        //default:  cs_log_dbg(D_TRACE, "camd35_recv returns rc=%d", rc); break;
    }

    return (rc);
}

/*
 *  server functions
 */

static void camd35_request_emm(ECM_REQUEST *er)
{
    int32_t i;
    time_t now;
    uchar mbuf[1024];
    struct s_client *cl = cur_client();
    struct s_reader *aureader = NULL, *rdr = NULL;

    if(er->selected_reader && !er->selected_reader->audisabled && ll_contains(cl->aureader_list, er->selected_reader))
        { aureader = er->selected_reader; }

    if(!aureader && cl->aureader_list)
    {
        LL_ITER itr = ll_iter_create(cl->aureader_list);
        while((rdr = ll_iter_next(&itr)))
        {
            if(emm_reader_match(rdr, er->caid, er->prid))
            {
                aureader = rdr;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!aureader)
        { return; }  // TODO

    uint16_t au_caid = aureader->caid;

    if(!au_caid && caid_is_bulcrypt(er->caid)) // Bulcrypt has 2 caids and aureader->caid can't be used. Use ECM_REQUEST caid for AU.
        { au_caid = er->caid; }

    time(&now);
    if(!memcmp(cl->lastserial, aureader->hexserial, 8))
        if(llabs(now - cl->last) < 180) { return; }

    memcpy(cl->lastserial, aureader->hexserial, 8);
    cl->last = now;

    if(au_caid)
    {
        cl->disable_counter = 0;
        cs_log("%s emm-request sent (reader=%s, caid=%04X, auprovid=%06X)",
               username(cur_client()), aureader->label, au_caid,
               aureader->auprovid ? aureader->auprovid : b2i(4, aureader->prid[0]));
    }
    else if(cl->disable_counter > 2)
        { return; }
    else
        { cl->disable_counter++; }

    memset(mbuf, 0, sizeof(mbuf));
    mbuf[2] = mbuf[3] = 0xff;           // must not be zero
    i2b_buf(2, er->srvid, mbuf + 8);

    //override request provid with auprovid if set in CMD05
    if(aureader->auprovid)
    {
        if(aureader->auprovid != er->prid)
            { i2b_buf(4, aureader->auprovid, mbuf + 12); }
        else
            { i2b_buf(4, er->prid, mbuf + 12); }
    }
    else
    {
        i2b_buf(4, er->prid, mbuf + 12);
    }

    i2b_buf(2, er->pid, mbuf + 16);
    mbuf[0] = 5;
    mbuf[1] = 111;
    if(au_caid)
    {
        mbuf[39] = 1;                           // no. caids
        mbuf[20] = au_caid >> 8;        // caid's (max 8)
        mbuf[21] = au_caid & 0xff;
        memcpy(mbuf + 40, aureader->hexserial, 6);  // serial now 6 bytes
        mbuf[47] = aureader->nprov;
        for(i = 0; i < aureader->nprov; i++)
        {
            if((au_caid >= 0x1700 && au_caid <= 0x1799)  ||  // Betacrypt
                    (au_caid >= 0x0600 && au_caid <= 0x0699))    // Irdeto (don't know if this is correct, cause I don't own a IRDETO-Card)
            {
                mbuf[48 + (i * 5)] = aureader->prid[i][0];
                memcpy(&mbuf[50 + (i * 5)], &aureader->prid[i][1], 3);
            }
            else
            {
                mbuf[48 + (i * 5)] = aureader->prid[i][2];
                mbuf[49 + (i * 5)] = aureader->prid[i][3];
                memcpy(&mbuf[50 + (i * 5)], &aureader->sa[i][0], 4); // for conax we need at least 4 Bytes
            }
        }
        //we think client/server protocols should deliver all information, and only readers should discard EMM
        mbuf[128] = (aureader->blockemm & EMM_GLOBAL && !(aureader->saveemm & EMM_GLOBAL)) ? 0 : 1;
        mbuf[129] = (aureader->blockemm & EMM_SHARED && !(aureader->saveemm & EMM_SHARED)) ? 0 : 1;
        mbuf[130] = (aureader->blockemm & EMM_UNIQUE && !(aureader->saveemm & EMM_UNIQUE)) ? 0 : 1;
        mbuf[127] = (aureader->blockemm & EMM_UNKNOWN && !(aureader->saveemm & EMM_UNKNOWN)) ? 0 : 1;
    }
    else        // disable emm
        { mbuf[20] = mbuf[39] = mbuf[40] = mbuf[47] = mbuf[49] = 1; }

    memcpy(mbuf + 10, mbuf + 20, 2);
    camd35_send(cl, mbuf, 0);       // send with data-len 111 for camd3 > 3.890
    mbuf[1]++;
    camd35_send(cl, mbuf, 0);       // send with data-len 112 for camd3 < 3.890
}

static void camd35_send_dcw(struct s_client *client, ECM_REQUEST *er)
{
    uchar *buf;
    buf = er->src_data; // get orig request

    if(!buf)
    {
        rdr_log(client->reader, "ERROR: src_data missing");
        return;
    }

    if(er->rc == E_INVALID && !client->c35_suppresscmd08)  //send normal CMD08
    {
        buf[0] = 0x08;
        buf[1] = 2;
        memset(buf + 20, 0, buf[1]);
        buf[22] = er->rc; //put rc in byte 22 - hopefully don't break legacy camd3
    }
    else if(er->rc == E_STOPPED)  //send sleep CMD08
    {
        buf[0] = 0x08;
        buf[1] = 2;
        buf[20] = 0;
        buf[21] = 0xFF;
        cs_log("%s stop request send", client->account->usr);
    }
    else
    {
        // Send CW
        if((er->rc < E_NOTFOUND) || (er->rc == E_FAKE))
        {
            if(buf[0] == 3)
                { memmove(buf + 20 + 16, buf + 20 + buf[1], 0x34); }
            buf[0]++;
            buf[1] = 16;
            camd35_cacheex_init_dcw(client, er);
            memcpy(buf + 20, er->cw, buf[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Send old CMD44 to prevent cascading problems with older mpcs/oscam versions
            buf[0] = 0x44;
            buf[1] = 0;
        }
    }
    camd35_send(client, buf, 0);
    camd35_request_emm(er);
}

static void camd35_process_ecm(uchar *buf, int buflen)
{
    ECM_REQUEST *er;

    if(!buf || buflen < 23)
        { return; }

    uint16_t ecmlen = SCT_LEN((&buf[20]));

    if(ecmlen > MAX_ECM_SIZE || ecmlen + 20 > buflen)
        { return; }

    if(!(er = get_ecmtask()))
        { return; }

    er->ecmlen = ecmlen;

    if(!cs_malloc(&er->src_data, 0x34 + 20 + er->ecmlen))
        { NULLFREE(er); return; }

    memcpy(er->src_data, buf, 0x34 + 20 + er->ecmlen);  // save request
    er->srvid = b2i(2, buf + 8);
    er->caid = b2i(2, buf + 10);
    er->prid = b2i(4, buf + 12);
    //er->pid  = b2i(2, buf+16); value is ecmtask idx see camd35_recv_chk 941
    memcpy(er->ecm, buf + 20, er->ecmlen);
    get_cw(cur_client(), er);
}

static void camd35_process_emm(uchar *buf, int buflen, int emmlen)
{
    EMM_PACKET epg;
    if(!buf || buflen < 20 || emmlen + 20 > buflen)
        { return; }
    memset(&epg, 0, sizeof(epg));
    epg.emmlen = emmlen;
    if(epg.emmlen < 3 || epg.emmlen > MAX_EMM_SIZE)
        { return; }
    memcpy(epg.caid, buf + 10, 2);
    memcpy(epg.provid, buf + 12 , 4);
    memcpy(epg.emm, buf + 20, epg.emmlen);
    do_emm(cur_client(), &epg);
}

int32_t camd35_tcp_connect(struct s_client *cl)
{
    if(cl->is_udp)    // check for udp client
    {
        if(!IP_ISSET(SIN_GET_ADDR(cl->udp_sa)))   // check ip is set
        {
            if(!(hostResolve(cl->reader)))   // no ip -> try to resolve ip of client
            {
                network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "no ip");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!cl->reader->tcp_connected)    // client not connected
    {
        int32_t handle = 0;
        handle = network_tcp_connection_open(cl->reader); // try to connect
        if(handle < 0)   // got no handle -> error!
        {
            cl->reader->last_s = 0; // set last send to zero
            cl->reader->last_g = 0; // set last receive to zero
            cl->last = 0; // set last client action to zero
            return (0);
        }

        cl->reader->tcp_connected = 1;
        cl->reader->card_status = CARD_INSERTED;
        cl->reader->last_s = time(NULL); // reset last send
        cl->reader->last_g = time(NULL); // reset last receive
        cl->last = time(NULL); // reset last client action
        cl->pfd = cl->udp_fd = handle;
    }
    if(!cl->udp_fd) { return (0); }  // Check if client has no handle -> error

    // check if client reached timeout
    if(cl->reader->tcp_rto && (cl->reader->last_s - cl->reader->last_g > cl->reader->tcp_rto))
    {
        if(!cl->is_udp) //tcp on timeout disconnect reader
        {
            network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "rto");
            return 0;
        }
        else //udp check to discover ip change on dynamic ip servers
        {
            IN_ADDR_T last_ip;
            IP_ASSIGN(last_ip, cl->ip);
            if(!hostResolve(cl->reader))
            {
                network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "no ip");
                return 0; 
            }
            if(!IP_EQUAL(last_ip, cl->ip))
            {
                network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "ip change");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return (1); // all ok
}

/*
 *  client functions
 */
static void camd35_send_keepalive(struct s_client *cl)
{

    if(cl->reader)
    {
        if(camd35_tcp_connect(cl))
        {
            if(cacheex_get_rdr_mode(cl->reader) > 1)
            {
                camd35_cacheex_push_request_remote_id(cl);
                return;
            }
            uint8_t rbuf[32];//minimal size
            memset(rbuf, 0, sizeof(rbuf));
            rbuf[0] = 55;
            rbuf[1] = 1;
            rbuf[2] = 0;
            camd35_send(cl, rbuf, 1); //send adds +20
        }
    }
}


static void camd35_send_keepalive_answer(struct s_client *cl)
{
    if(check_client(cl) && cl->account)
    {
        uint8_t rbuf[32];//minimal size
        memset(rbuf, 0, sizeof(rbuf));
        rbuf[0] = 55;
        rbuf[1] = 1;
        rbuf[2] = 0;
        camd35_send(cl, rbuf, 1); //send adds +20
    }
}


static int32_t camd35_client_init(struct s_client *cl)
{
    unsigned char md5tmp[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int32_t no_delay = 1;

    cs_strncpy((char *)cl->upwd, cl->reader->r_pwd, sizeof(cl->upwd));
    i2b_buf(4, crc32(0L, MD5((unsigned char *)cl->reader->r_usr, strlen(cl->reader->r_usr), md5tmp), 16), cl->ucrc);
    if (!aes_set_key_alloc(&cl->aes_keys, (char *)MD5(cl->upwd, strlen((char *)cl->upwd), md5tmp)))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    cl->crypted=1;

    rdr_log(cl->reader, "proxy %s:%d", cl->reader->device, cl->reader->r_port);

    if(!cl->is_udp && cacheex_get_rdr_mode(cl->reader) < 2)
        setsockopt(cl->udp_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&no_delay, sizeof(no_delay));

    if(cl->reader->keepalive)
        camd35_send_keepalive(cl);

    if(cacheex_get_rdr_mode(cl->reader) == 2)
        camd35_cacheex_send_push_filter(cl, 2);

    return(0);
}


static void camd35_idle(void)
{
    struct s_client *cl = cur_client();

    if(!cl->reader)
        { return; }

    if(cl->reader->keepalive) 
    {
        camd35_send_keepalive(cl);
    }
    else if(cl->reader->tcp_ito>0) // only check if user added an inactivity timeout
    {
        //inactivity timeout check
        time_t now;
        int32_t time_diff;
        time(&now);
        time_diff = llabs(now - cl->reader->last_s);
        if(time_diff>cl->reader->tcp_ito)
        {
            if(check_client(cl) && cl->reader->tcp_connected && cl->reader->ph.type==MOD_CONN_TCP)
            {
                rdr_log_dbg(cl->reader, D_READER, "inactive_timeout, close connection (fd=%d)", cl->pfd);
                network_tcp_connection_close(cl->reader, "inactivity");
            }
            else
                { cl->reader->last_s = now; }
        }
    }
}

static void *camd35_server(struct s_client *client, uchar *mbuf, int32_t n)
{
    if(!client || !mbuf)
        { return NULL; }

    if(client->reader)
    {
        client->reader->last_g = time(NULL);  // last receive is now
        if(mbuf[0] == 6 || mbuf[0] == 19)  // check for emm command
        {
            client->reader->last_s = time(NULL); // fixup: last send is now (if client is only sending emms connection would be dropped!)
        }
        rdr_log(client->reader, "SERVER last = %d, last_s = %d, last_g = %d", (int) client->last, (int) client->reader->last_s, (int) client->reader->last_g);
    }
    client->last = time(NULL); // last client action is now


    switch(mbuf[0])
    {
    case  0:    // ECM
    case  3:    // ECM (cascading)
        camd35_process_ecm(mbuf, n);
        break;
    case  6:    // EMM
    case 19:  // EMM
        if(n > 2)
            { camd35_process_emm(mbuf, n, mbuf[1]); }
        break;
    case 55:
        //keepalive msg
        camd35_send_keepalive_answer(client);
        break;
    default:
        if (!camd35_cacheex_server(client, mbuf))
            cs_log("unknown [cs357x/cs378x] command from %s! (%d) n=%d", username(client), mbuf[0], n);
    }

    return NULL; //to prevent compiler message
}

static int32_t camd35_send_ecm(struct s_client *client, ECM_REQUEST *er)
{
    static const char *typtext[] = {"ok", "invalid", "sleeping"};

    if(client->stopped)
    {
        if(er->srvid == client->lastsrvid && er->caid == client->lastcaid)
        {
            cs_log("%s is stopped - requested by server (%s)",
                   client->reader->label, typtext[client->stopped]);
            return (-1);
        }
        else
        {
            client->stopped = 0;
        }
    }

    client->lastsrvid = er->srvid;
    client->lastcaid = er->caid;
    client->lastpid = er->pid;

    if(!camd35_tcp_connect(client)) { return -1; }

    client->reader->card_status = CARD_INSERTED; //for udp

    uint8_t *buf;
    if(!cs_malloc(&buf, er->ecmlen + 20 + 15))
    { return -1; }

    memset(buf, 0, 20);
    memset(buf + 20, 0xff, er->ecmlen + 15);
    buf[1] = er->ecmlen;
    i2b_buf(2, er->srvid, buf + 8);
    i2b_buf(2, er->caid, buf + 10);
    i2b_buf(4, er->prid, buf + 12);
    i2b_buf(2, er->idx, buf + 16);
    buf[18] = 0xff;
    buf[19] = 0xff;
    memcpy(buf + 20, er->ecm, er->ecmlen);
    int32_t rc = ((camd35_send(client, buf, 0) < 1) ? (-1) : 0);

    NULLFREE(buf);
    return rc;
}

static int32_t camd35_send_emm(EMM_PACKET *ep)
{
    uint8_t *buf;
    struct s_client *cl = cur_client();

    if(!camd35_tcp_connect(cl)) { return 0; }
    cl->reader->card_status = CARD_INSERTED; //for udp

    if(!cs_malloc(&buf, ep->emmlen + 20 + 15))
    { return -1; }

    memset(buf, 0, 20);
    memset(buf + 20, 0xff, ep->emmlen + 15);

    buf[0] = 0x06;
    buf[1] = ep->emmlen;
    memcpy(buf + 10, ep->caid, 2);
    memcpy(buf + 12, ep->provid, 4);
    memcpy(buf + 20, ep->emm, ep->emmlen);

    int32_t rc = ((camd35_send_without_timeout(cl, buf, 0) < 1) ? 0 : 1);

    NULLFREE(buf);
    return rc;  
}

static int32_t camd35_recv_chk(struct s_client *client, uchar *dcw, int32_t *rc, uchar *buf, int32_t rc2 __attribute__((unused)))
{
    uint16_t idx;
    static const char *typtext[] = {"ok", "invalid", "sleeping"};
    struct s_reader *rdr = client->reader;
    rdr->last_g = time(NULL);  // last receive is now

    // reading CMD05 Emm request and set serial
    if(buf[0] == 0x05 && buf[1] == 111)
    {

        //cs_log("CMD05: %s", cs_hexdump(1, buf, buf[1], tmp, sizeof(tmp)));
        rdr->nprov = 0; //reset if number changes on reader change
        rdr->nprov = buf[47];
        rdr->caid = b2i(2, buf + 20);

        int32_t i;
        for(i = 0; i < rdr->nprov; i++)
        {
            if(((rdr->caid >= 0x1700) && (rdr->caid <= 0x1799))  ||     // Betacrypt
                    ((rdr->caid >= 0x0600) && (rdr->caid <= 0x0699)))   // Irdeto (don't know if this is correct, cause I don't own a IRDETO-Card)
            {
                rdr->prid[i][0] = buf[48 + (i * 5)];
                memcpy(&rdr->prid[i][1], &buf[50 + (i * 5)], 3);
            }
            else
            {
                rdr->prid[i][2] = buf[48 + (i * 5)];
                rdr->prid[i][3] = buf[49 + (i * 5)];
                memcpy(&rdr->sa[i][0], &buf[50 + (i * 5)], 4);
            }
        }

        memcpy(rdr->hexserial, buf + 40, 6);
        rdr->hexserial[6] = 0;
        rdr->hexserial[7] = 0;

        if(cfg.getblockemmauprovid)
        {
            rdr->blockemm = 0;
            rdr->blockemm |= (buf[128] == 1) ? 0 : EMM_GLOBAL;
            rdr->blockemm |= (buf[129] == 1) ? 0 : EMM_SHARED;
            rdr->blockemm |= (buf[130] == 1) ? 0 : EMM_UNIQUE;
            rdr->blockemm |= (buf[127] == 1) ? 0 : EMM_UNKNOWN;
            rdr->auprovid = b2i(4, buf + 12);
        }
        cs_log("%s CMD05 AU request for caid: %04X auprovid: %06X",
               rdr->label,
               rdr->caid,
               rdr->auprovid);
    }

    bool rc_invalid = 0;
    if(buf[0] == 0x08
            && ((rdr->ph.type == MOD_CONN_TCP && !cfg.c35_tcp_suppresscmd08)
                || (rdr->ph.type == MOD_CONN_UDP
                    && !cfg.c35_udp_suppresscmd08)))
    {
        if(buf[21] == 0xFF)
        {
            client->stopped = 2; // server says sleep
            rdr->card_status = NO_CARD;
        }
        else
        {
            if(config_enabled(WITH_LB) && cfg.lb_mode)
            {
                rc_invalid = 1;
            }else{
                client->stopped = 1; // server says invalid
                rdr->card_status = CARD_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        cs_log("%s CMD08 (%02X - %d) stop request by server (%s)", rdr->label, buf[21], buf[21], typtext[client->stopped]);
    }

    if (camd35_cacheex_recv_chk(client, buf))
        { return -1; }

    if(buf[0] == 55)  //keepalive answer
        { return -1; }

    // CMD44: old reject command introduced in mpcs
    // keeping this for backward compatibility
    if((buf[0] != 1) && (buf[0] != 0x44) && (buf[0] != 0x08))
        { return (-1); }

    idx = b2i(2, buf + 16);

    camd35_cacheex_recv_ce1_cwc_info(client, buf, idx);

    *rc = ((buf[0] != 0x44) && (buf[0] != 0x08));
    if(rc_invalid){
        *rc = 2;  // INVALID sent by CMD08
    }

    memcpy(dcw, buf + 20, 16);
    return (idx);
}

/*
 *  module definitions
 */
#ifdef MODULE_CAMD35
void module_camd35(struct s_module *ph)
{
    ph->ptab.nports = 1;
    ph->ptab.ports[0].s_port = cfg.c35_port;

    ph->desc = "cs357x";
    ph->type = MOD_CONN_UDP;
    ph->large_ecm_support = 1;
    ph->listenertype = LIS_CAMD35UDP;
    IP_ASSIGN(ph->s_ip, cfg.c35_srvip);
    ph->s_handler = camd35_server;
    ph->recv = camd35_recv;
    ph->send_dcw = camd35_send_dcw;
    ph->c_init = camd35_client_init;
    ph->c_recv_chk = camd35_recv_chk;
    ph->c_send_ecm = camd35_send_ecm;
    ph->c_send_emm = camd35_send_emm;
    ph->c_idle = camd35_idle;
    camd35_cacheex_module_init(ph);
    ph->num = R_CAMD35;
}
#endif

#ifdef MODULE_CAMD35_TCP
void module_camd35_tcp(struct s_module *ph)
{
    ph->desc = "cs378x";
    ph->type = MOD_CONN_TCP;
    ph->large_ecm_support = 1;
    ph->listenertype = LIS_CAMD35TCP;
    ph->ptab = cfg.c35_tcp_ptab;
    IP_ASSIGN(ph->s_ip, cfg.c35_tcp_srvip);
    ph->s_handler = camd35_server;
    ph->recv = camd35_recv;
    ph->send_dcw = camd35_send_dcw;
    ph->c_init = camd35_client_init;
    ph->c_recv_chk = camd35_recv_chk;
    ph->c_send_ecm = camd35_send_ecm;
    ph->c_send_emm = camd35_send_emm;
    ph->c_idle = camd35_idle;
    camd35_cacheex_module_init(ph);
    ph->num = R_CS378X;
}
#endif
```

Comment: и в чём вопрос? в изучении статистики, сколько людей знакомых с протоколом?

Comment: День добрый. Советую почитать про [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и выделить основное в своём вопросе.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что нужно каким то образом обработать исходные данные (видимо зашифровать), оформить их в UDP-пакет и отправить на сервер. А по получению ответа - воспроизвести все в обратном порядке.